# Library type remote web service calls and HttpClient ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, deadlock, async-await

Suppose you are creating a library to be shared among multiple applications some that may exist as fully synchronous codebases. The purpose of this library is to execute web service calls using `HttpClient` using async await.

Given this scenario similar to

```
var client = new HttpClient(....) { .... }
var response = await client.GetAsync("Users/").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

should all async await usage include the usage of `ConfigureAwait(false)` at all times?

Prior to the inclusion of that false setting this code would seemingly deadlock when consumed in a synchronous application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should include `ConfigureAwait` in all library code. I don't recommend synchronous blocking on `async` methods, but it is doable if you consistently use `ConfigureAwait`.

As a side effect, `ConfigureAwait` will also enhance your performance.

I describe why this works in detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and in [a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Stephen, the resources I found that lead me to using ConfigureAwait to fix deadlock or whatever chaos occurred without, I seemed to infer I should use this at all places in a library but I try to always have explicit references not just assumptions in why I do things.